# Autocommand to run :Prettier on :w

Tags: neovim, autocmd, lsp

I am working in a React (TypeScript) project. I am using LSP with Neovim and have TypeScript Server installed.

Right now, after I make a change, I have to run `:Prettier` followed by `:w`. I'm getting tired of doing this.

I thought LSP might have had a format on save feature, but I guess not since it isn't working.

How do I go about creating an auto-command that will run `:Prettier` each time I `:w`?

My config files can be [found on GitHub](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/.dotfiles/tree/main/.config/nvim).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `:h BufWritePre` autocmd event.

```
augroup Prettier
  au!
  au BufWritePre *.tsx,*.ts,*.js,*.html,*.css  Prettier
augroup END
```

For explanation, see `:h autocmd`.

Comment: React TypeScript files have the extension `.tsx` but I want to run Prettier for `.tsx`, `.ts`, `.js`, `.html` and `.css`, what will this look like?

Comment: @J86 answer edited.